# Ways to better study глаголы движения

Tags: грамматика, обучение, глаголы-движения

I'm terrible with movement verbs, I never use them well, especially with prefixes, the way to use them changes a lot!!! I get incredibly confuse.

So if someone has a good book reference regarding this topic, I'll appreciate it, especially if it is online. And also if someone could share tips to better understand how to use this глаголы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some links for you to look at some pictures that explain the general meaning of different prefixes. Fortunately, with verbs of motion these really have more or less fixed meanings.

http://learnrussian.rt.com/grammar-tables/verbs-of-motion-with-prefixes/
http://www.alphadictionary.com/rusgrammar/vom.html

As for the overall use, I like this "practical" explanation of typical patterns of use for *indefinite vs. specific verbs of motion*:
http://www.public.asu.edu/~deliving/russgram/vuses.htm

Just remember that the choice of aspect is a matter of your point of view. It just sounds weird when you suddenly make a choice vastly different from any that a native speaker would. Sometimes it contradicts the nature of the verbs, sometimes not.

Memorise some typical constructions where it is virtually impossible to change interpretation: if you *"go to school"* (study there), it is always *"ходить в школу"* (habitual). *"Идти в школу"* is only when you are going to the school, like, right now or soon (specific, definite motion).

Comment: "Learn Russian" is a fantastic site. I really love  the speakers there: they are true actors! Thanks for the link, Shady_arc.

Answer (score 2):

The usual term in English is "verbs of motion" rather than "movement verbs". In any case, I think the best way to learn to use these is to use them a lot with native speakers. You could discuss traveling, going to other cities, arriving and departing, and so on.

There is a whole book on this topic: Russian Motion Verbs for Intermediate Students, by William Mahota.