# Motion Verbs - Deciding which verb to use when

Tags: глаголы, глаголы-движения

I'm struggling to understand which motion verbs should be used in which situation.

The verbs that I have been studying are:

> идти/пойти
>
> ехать/поехать
>
> ходить
>
> ездить

When should I use these verbs? What are the differences between them?

Comment: Related https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/what-is-the-difference-between-the-prefixes-%d0%bf%d0%be-and-%d1%83-in-verbs-of-motion

Comment: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/4448/ways-to-better-study-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f

Comment: basically if look at the right pane of this page under Linked and Related you'll find a bunch of similar questions, likewise if you click the tag `глаголы-движения` under your own question... this particular topic is fairly extensively covered on this website, but if you wish to know something not covered previously you might want to narrow down your question to specific aspect of their usage